# asignar resultado de un select a una variable en PL/SQL Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

buenas tardes.

Me entregaron un procedimiento almacenado el cual se usa con la aplicación PL/SQL Developer, con una base de datos en Oracle. (detallo esto porque soy principiante en con Oracle)

y me pidieron agregarle una variable y que esta capturara el resultado de un SELECT para ser ocupado en un if, este es el código que hay:

```
Function Fn_Scf_TraeMonto (pAccNumber Varchar2, pFechaVenc Date, pTOO Varchar2) Return Number

Is

  -- esto el lo que agregué yo
  resultado  Numeric := SELECT count(*) from dlinquency d where d.account_number = pAccNumber and d.due_date >= to_date(sysdate, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
  -- esto ya estaba
  nMontoLoan Numeric := 0;


  Begin
   If pTOO in ('9282', '9283') and resultado > 0
      THEN
      ---
```

De ahí el código sigue pero tengo el problema de que no sé cómo ese select guardarlo en la variable, he encontrado hartos links pero creo que ninguno me sirve o no se bien como aplicarlo a mi caso.

En sql sé cómo se hace, declaro mi variable y después hago un select @variable = valor...

pero para Oracle no doy con la forma.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que tratas de hacer se hace en **Oracle** a través de **cursores implícitos**:

```
select campo into x
from tabla 
where condicion;
```

Como ves aquí se almacena en la **variable x** el valor que se devuelve en la consulta.

Un **cursor** es el nombre para un área memoria privada que contiene información procedente de la ejecución de una sentencia **select**. Cada **cursor** tiene unos atributos que nos devuelven información útil sobre el estado del **cursor** en la ejecución de la **sentencia SQL**. Existen dos tipos de cursores, **cursores implícitos y cursores explícitos**.

Los **cursores implícitos** se utilizan para operaciones **select into**. Se usan cuando la consulta devuelve un único registro.

Los **cursores explícitos** son declarados y controlados por el programador. Se utilizan cuando la consulta devuelve un conjunto de registros. Ocasionalmente también se utilizan en consultas que devuelven un único registro por razones de eficiencia. Son más rápidos.

Dicho todo esto tu ejemplo quedaría como:

```
select count(*) into total
from dlinquency d
where d.account_number = pAccNumber and d.due_date >= to_date(sysdate, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Usando select into guardamos en la variable total el valor devuelto por tu consulta

Comment: Cabe aclarar que los cursores implícitos no sólo *"se usan cuando la consulta devuelve un único registro"*. Hay cursores implícitos para varios registros; y en complemento, un cursor explícito puede usarse para obtener un registro único.

Comment: Hola buenos días, apliqué tu solución pero me arrojó un error, pero fue error mio, después del "Is" tengo que declarar la variable y dentro del "Begin" hacer la consulta que tú dices, yo estaba tratando de hacer todo altiro y donde no corresponde. Muchas Gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: es la columna "due_date" de tipo DATE?
Si es así es innecesario usar la función "TO_DATE" con el resultado de la función SYSDATE ya que este produce un valor de tipo DATE.

Answer (score 0):

```
t_select  varchar2(1000);
```

t_from    varchar2(200);
t_where   varchar2(2000);

BEGIN
t_select := 'select CAMPO1,CAMPO2,CAMPO3';
t_from := ' from TABLA';
t_where := ' where CAMPO1 = '''||valor_texto||''' and CAMPO2 = '''||valor_texto||''' ';

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).